# Not sure where to start with JavaFX minesweeper GUI

Tags: java, javafx

I recently started a minesweeper project in Java. I planned to first develop the game mechanics while using the Console as output, but now I want to develop a GUI using the code I have. The problem is I have very little experience in GUI design.

One of my previous experiences in JavaFX was designing a Chess game. For the chess board, I created a 2D ImageView grid in the fxml. The images each ImageView would display would change as the pieces moved.

For my minesweeper game, I've implemented a variably sized board so I can't just create another ImageView 2D array again. I'm wondering if there is something in JavaFX that I don't know about that could help me approach this issue.

I would just like to know a good way to display the board of tiles itself. All the other GUI aspects of the game, I could figure out later.

The best thing that I could think of right now with what I know about JavaFX is that I can create a 2D ImageView array with the max size of the board. I could set all the height and width of the unused tiles to 0. However, even though this is the best idea that I have, I feel that it is a very bad way to approach the problem.

Here are the fields of the Board object

```java
public class Board {
    public final static int EASY_SIZE = 8;
    public final static int MED_SIZE = 12;
    public final static int HARD_SIZE = 15;

    public final static int MIN_SIZE = 5;
    public final static int MAX_SIZE = 26;

    public int size;
    protected int mine_count;

    public boolean ended = false;

    protected Tile[][] board;
```

The board output to the Console. The board.display() function:

```java
public void display() {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(mine_count + " remaining mines");
    for (int i = 0; i< 10 && i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(" _");
    }
    for(int i = 10; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(" __");
    }
    System.out.println();
    // For each row
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        // For each col
        for (int c = 0; c < size && c < 10; c++) {
            // if the tile is flagged
            if (board[r][c].flag == true) {
                System.out.print("|F");
            }
            // else if the tile has not been clicked
            else if (board[r][c].clicked == false) {
                System.out.print("|#");
            }
            // else if mine clicked
            else if (board[r][c].mine == true) {
                System.out.print("|*");
            }
            // else if zero adj_mines
            else if (board[r][c].adj_mines == 0) {
                System.out.print("|_");
            }
            // else show number
            else {
                System.out.print("|" + board[r][c].adj_mines);
            }
        }
        for (int c = 10; c < size; c++) {
            // if the tile is flagged
            if (board[r][c].flag == true) {
                System.out.print("|F_");
            }
            // else if the tile has not been clicked
            else if (board[r][c].clicked == false) {
                System.out.print("|#_");
            }
            // else if mine clicked
            else if (board[r][c].mine == true) {
                System.out.print("|*_");
            }
            // else if zero adj_mines
            else if (board[r][c].adj_mines == 0) {
                System.out.print("|__");
            }
            // else show number
            else {
                System.out.print("|" + board[r][c].adj_mines + "_");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("| " + r);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

...
Since my question is regarding what sort of JavaFX layout I could use to approach the problem, I started looking more into my options. In my previous experiences in JavaFX, I designed all of the GUI elements in an FXML file, but I realize that since I'm not certain about the size of the board on bootup, I should not be doing this.

Instead, I'm planning to use a GridPane layout and I will change my Tile class to extend Button to set an EventHandler on left and right mouse clicks. If anyone has insight on why this might not work, I would love to hear it, but otherwise, I'll report back if this works on not!

Comment: Is this problem about dynamically resizing the data structure used to store the nodes or what exactly is the issue?

Comment: You wrote: _I ... first develop the game ... using the Console as output_ Looks to me like you posted the code for your Console version. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes the display method is the one that prints out the Tile[][] board to the console. I didn't know if it would help clarify how my game is set up

Comment: My problem is asking what sort of layout can I use to show a 2D board of equally sized Tile objects. Originally, I was thinking a 2D array of ImageViews but that seems sloppy.

Comment: Stick with the gridPane You may want to checkout ColumnConstraints and RowConstraints for the gridpane but if each tile is the same size it may not matter just my 2 cents

Comment: [TilePane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html) would probably work also.